# Saving multiple images using File.WriteAllBytes saves only the last one

Tags: c#

i'm trying to save multiple images with File.WriteAllBytes(), even after i tried to seperate between the saves with 'Thread.Sleep()' it's not working..

my code:

```
       byte[] signatureBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(model.Signature);
        byte[] idBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(model.IdCapture);

        //Saving the images as PNG extension.
        FileManager.SaveFile(signatureBytes, dirName, directoryPath, signatureFileName);
        FileManager.SaveFile(idBytes, dirName, directoryPath, captureFileName);
```

SaveFile Function:

```
    public static void SaveFile(byte[] imageBytes, string dirName, string path, string fileName, string fileExt = "jpg")
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dirName)
            && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(path)
            && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)
            && imageBytes.Length > 0)
        {
            var dirPath = Path.Combine(path, dirName);

            var di = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);

            if (!di.Exists)
                di.Create();

            if (di.Exists)
            {
                File.WriteAllBytes(dirPath + $@"\{fileName}.{fileExt}", imageBytes);
            }
        }
        else
            throw new Exception("File cannot be created, one of the parameters are null or empty.");
    }
```

Comment: What does *not working* mean? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: Yea can only guess based on this code sample, but maybe you are reusing the same file names for both calls

Comment: The names of the files are diffrent, there are no exceptions. Only results with 1 file saved at the end of the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the possibility (as mentioned by @Daniel) that you're overwriting the same file, I'm not sure about this code:

```
        var di = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);

        if (!di.Exists)
            di.Create();

        if (di.Exists)
        {
            ...
        }
```

I'd be surprised if, having called `di.Create()`, the `Exists` property is updated. In fact, it is *not* updated - I checked.

So, if the directory did *not* exist, then you won't enter the conditional part even after creating the directory. Could that explain your issue?

Answer (score 2):

File.WriteAllBytes():

"Creates a new file, writes the specified byte array to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten"

As expecify in :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx

So if you can only see the last one, you are overwriting the file.

Comment: As i mentioned comment before, i'm using diffrent byte arrays and diffrent names for the files.. that's why i'm confused about it